# how to find the values of trignometric rations of angles with closer to 90 degree?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve some trigonometric sums and I have stuck at how to find the values of trigonometric rations of angles with closer to 90 degree?like cos(270 + Q ), sin(450 - Q) etc.

We solve cos(240) like this:-

cos(180 + 60) =  -cos60

but How can I solve the same equation like this cos(270 - 30) ??
I know that I can Solve this equation by cos(180 + 60) , some times you have give like cos(270 -Q) or sin(450 -Q) ..etc

Also sorry for confusing title cause I can't find some proper title.(edits it ,please if know good one)

Comment: In the same way as $\cos(180^\circ+ \theta) = -\cos(\theta)$, you could use  $\cos(270^\circ- \phi) = -\sin(\phi) = -\cos(90^\circ-\phi)$

Comment: @Henry thanks sir!!You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

In the same way as $$\cos(180^\circ+ \theta) = -\cos(\theta)$$ you could use $$\cos(270^\circ- \phi) = -\sin(\phi) = -\cos(90^\circ-\phi)$$